# Authorization & Authentication in RESTful Web Services with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a Web API with Spring Boot.
I found an article describing how to secure RESTful Web service on Spring project with the following URL:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/5/

This approach is the way I would like to follow.
I downloaded the source code (yummynoddlebar), but they secure the web service by checking Base64 encoded userID&password on request header. Sending those information is not secure. I would like to send JWT token in request header instead, but I cannot find any articles describing how to intercept a request and authorize user with JWT.

I am new to Spring world, It seems Spring team moves forward from XML to Annotation way.
When I google Spring article, I am confused sometimes with XML configuration.
I would like to use annotation rather than XML for configuration like the yummynoddlebar did.

[Update]

I could use a code from the following URL to authenticate User in Spring project, but I still need to know how to intercept request.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-authentication

Comment: Let Spring handle that for you. Not sure what JWT is but alas, you probably want to add a filter that extracts the header and passes it to an AuthenticationProvider. Don't try to reinvent the wheel but let Spring Security do the heavy lifting and you only need to implement the integration points.